# Develop a “Credit Risk Scoring System” with R

Tags: data-mining, r, predictive-modeling

I want to achieve during my internship a credit risk scoring system based on "credit german dataset".

I develop a model with R using logistic regression and i validate it. Now i must use this model to calculate a new applicant score and deduce whether good or bad.

I don't know how to proceed?

Comment: A Google search yields many papers and presentations that can help you get started, e.g.: http://www.stat.fsu.edu/~jfrade/HOMEWORKS/STA5168/FRADE_STA5168_paper.pdf , https://smartdrill.com/pdf/Credit%20Risk%20Analysis.pdf , http://www.pomsmeetings.org/confpapers/007/007-0210.pdf, https://bib.irb.hr/datoteka/466476.sarlija_soric_vlah_vojvodic.pdf. Here are several books: https://books.google.com/books?id=bbaTr3bb110C , https://books.google.com/books?id=7LlGfPvOJLoC

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to decide how you evaluate "good" vs "bad", which means picking a metric. From the top of my head you have three choices:

- accuracy: simplest, but potentially misleading (if you have few defaults and predict all 0s, you still get high accuracy)
- logloss: penalize assigning a high def probability to good quality credit and vice versa
- ROC: sort the credit from best to worst.

Once you've made your pick, make sure your model can generate predictions in the right format (i.e. output probabilities and not just 0/1) and the go through the training / validation / test paradigm. This should get you started.